# IPSet with IP6Tables ERROR

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, iptables, ipv6

Can someone please solve my headache and tell me how to fix this?

```
[root@www ~]# ip6tables -I INPUT -m set --match-set blacklist6 src -J DROP

ip6tables v1.4.7: Couldn't load match `set':/lib64/xtables/libip6t_set.so: cannot open
shared object file: No such file or directory

Try `ip6tables -h' or 'ip6tables --help' for more information.

[root@www xtables]#
```

The blacklist6 is an ipset inet6 list that I want to blocklist from.

ipset-x86_64 is installed
the blacklist6 exists
this same command with "iptables" and "blacklist" work's fine(IPv4) but I also need an IPv6 blacklist.

I don't want to resort to other software. I want to use IPset & IPtables due to their advantages and my spending days figuring out how to work with them already.;)

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Output of `yum list '*xtables*'`:

```
[root@www ~]$ sudo yum list '*xtable*'
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                            |  28 kB     00:00     
 * base: mirror.checkdomain.de
 * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
 * extras: mirror.checkdomain.de
 * ius: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * updates: mirror.checkdomain.de
Xen4CentOS                                               | 3.4 kB     00:00     
adobe-linux-x86_64                                       |  951 B     00:00     
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00     
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00     
iRedMail                                                 |  951 B     00:00     
ius                                                      | 2.1 kB     00:00     
nginx                                                    | 2.9 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00     
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

Comment: Looks like something isn't installed that should be...`No such file or directory`

Comment: But what is it that's missing? I tried Googling just the libip6t_set.so and I can't find anything about it AT ALL.

Comment: Please post the output from each of the commands `uname -a` and `virt-what` (install the latter, if it is not already present).

Comment: Please post the output of `ipset -v`. Also, what version of CentOS do you have?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
sudo yum install xtables-addons xtables-addons-kmod
```

It *should* install the missing `libip6t_set.so` file.

Comment: No package xtables-addons available.
No package xtables-addons-kmod available.

Comment: @JohnDoe Please add the output of `sudo yum list '*xtable*'` to your question.